# no one and no one else differences

Tags: adverbs

> 1. She has **no one else** to look after her but me.
> 2. She has **no one** to look after her but me.

Which is correct? What is the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: _But me_ means _except for me_, so  it is, strictly speaking, unnecessary to use _else_ (other than me) in the same sentence.

Answer (score 0):

**"But me"** means *"except for me"*.  So, you need not use *'else'* to exclude *'me'* from *'no one'* in your example :

> *"She has no one **else** to look after her **but** me."* (Here, *'else'* is unnecessary.)

Your second sentence is okay :

> *"She has **no one** to look after her but me."*

Or, you could also say :

> *"She has **none but me** to look after her."*